# Why do I get NumberFormatException when displaying data in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I  create a Spark 2.2 dataframe using SparkR, thus:

```
df1 <- SparkR::sql("SELECT created_at, user.utc_offset as utc_offset FROM tweets0 
WHERE racist = true ")
```

and it has schema:

```
root
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- utc_offset: string (nullable = true)
```

when I try:

```
showDF(df1, numRows = 20, truncate = TRUE)
```

or `head(df1)`
I get:

```
ERROR RBackendHandler: showString on 4 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt it happens in this code. Best bet - configuration is messed up.

Comment: Thanks! I had my versions of Spark mixed up. If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually no it has come back. Don't know how I fixed it yesterday!!